# A word for raising your voice (not shouting/yelling)

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm currently writing a book in English, which is not my first language, and I just can't find the right word for talking with your voice raised, except for shouting and yelling..

"Alejandro, come talk to your dad on the phone," she ... from the living room.

I don't know which word fits the blank; said is too simple/boring and doesn't express the tone of the voice as much as the other words, but yelled and shouted are too aggressive.. I also thought of 'called out', but I'm not sure..

I'm really confused, someone help me..

Comment: Just 'called' is fine here ('called out' is rather less convivial-sounding). 'Call' can often be a useful quotative verb.

Comment: *Boomed* or *announced* or other words of grandeur could work.

Comment: A loud voice . . .

Comment: In such a plainly neutral context, *yell* and *shout* actually don't strike me as very aggressive at all. Yelling *to* someone just indicates an increase in volume, yelling *at* someone indicates some level of aggression.

Comment: English has so many colorful verbs that would fit here. Detective stories/thrillers are full of them.

Answer (score 1):

- she **bellowed** from the living room. [strong, in a deep voice]
- she **sang out** from the living room. [loud but easy to hear]
- she **trilled** from the living room. [like a bird]
- she **called out** from the living room [loud but not shouting, commonly used]
- she **intoned** from the living room [to utter in singing tones]
- she **urged** him from the living room [to encourage, slight anxiety]

Sorry, I am not going to do the dictionary thing today.

You should choose a word that matches the mother's personality.

Answer (score -1):

How about the verb, to *project*.

> project, verb
>
> > cause (a sound, especially the voice) to be heard at a distance.

When someone is being loud, not yelling, but their voice goes very far and is loud to those near, they are "projecting their voice." It would not be incorrect to simply say, "project" and drop "their voice."

> "Alejandro, come talk to your dad on the phone," she **projected** from the living room.

Otherwise, perhaps just use an adverb like *loudly* to modify "called out," "said," etc.